# How to fix range error in filter formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to filter data from a transportation sheet onto a dashboard sheet, but make the information editable. I have this code written, but keep getting an error on the

```
var filteredRange = sourceSheet.getRange(filterFormula);
```

stating

> Range not found.

This is my code:

```
function updateDashboard() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Transportation');
  var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dashboard');

  // Clear previous data in the destination range
  destinationSheet.getRange('L7:S1000').clearContent();

  // Apply the filter formula to get the filtered range
  var filterFormula = '=FILTER(Transportation!D2:K,(Transportation!C2:C998 >= D2) * (Transportation!C2:C <= D3) * (Transportation!K2:K <> FALSE))';
  var filteredRange = sourceSheet.getRange(filterFormula);

  // Copy the filtered data to the destination sheet
  filteredRange.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange('L7'), { contentsOnly: true });

  // Set the destination range as an editable range
  var dataRange = destinationSheet.getRange('L7:S1000');
  var protection = dataRange.protect().setDescription('Editable Range');
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

What populates after the code is entered:

[image]

What sort of edits I want to make, see the highlighted row:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your code I noticed a couple of things that might be the root cause of your issue.

- #### **The 'filteredFormula'  Variable**

```
var filterFormula = '=FILTER(Transportation!D2:K,(Transportation!C2:C998 >= D2) * (Transportation!C2:C <= D3) * (Transportation!K2:K <> FALSE))';
```

I understand what you are trying to apply that formula in a cell, however in the way you are passing it, the variable only contains a ‘string’ and it is not ‘applying’ it at all. What I recommend using is the method “ setFormula()”. You will have to define first which cell it should be placed:

```js
var targetCell = sourceSheet.getRange(“A1”) // cell where you will be setting the formula
Var  filterFormula =  targetCell.setFormula(“=FILTER(Transportation!D2:K,(Transportation!C2:C998 >= D2) * (Transportation!C2:C <= D3) * (Transportation!K2:K <> FALSE))”)
```

- #### Working with ranges for the variable 'filteredRange'

On this part, I understood you wanted to take the values displayed after the formula ran and used them to determine the range of the filtered data (feel free to correct me if I’m wrong, please).

```js
var filteredRange = sourceSheet.getRange(filterFormula);
```

But using it like that is not fetching the values after the calculation of the formula, in addition to my previous suggestion I would recommend this:

```js
var filteredRange = filterFormula.getDisplayValues()
```

According to the [setFormula() documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#return_147), it returns the range ready to be used for chaining, so we could do it with “[getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)” which returns exactly what you can see after the formula calculation (in other words, the filtered data).

I’m still missing some additional testing, but in theory with the aforementioned changes it should address the issues you are facing, if I encounter anything else that could be of help I’ll be editing my answer. Also, if you have questions let me know! :)

#### References

- [setFormula() references](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)
- [getDisplayValues() references](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [Variables in Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)

Comment: Thank you! Your advice helped with having the formula populate correctly!
 However, I am trying to have data be editable, on the Dashboard Sheet, see sample photos added to the initial question. I essentially want to be able to change the data that populates on the Dashboard, and then that change be seen on the Transportation Sheet. Right now when I try to change the a value populated by the formula on the Dashboard, it overrides the formula. Not sure if this possible though, or if I am even on the right track with this initial code. If I am not making sense, I can give more clarification!